# paste dataframe name with colnames

Tags: r

I have a dataframe called A. There are six columns in A.

```
A
Dxa  Dxb  Dxc  Dxd  Dxe  Dxf
```

I am wondering how could I instruct to paste A$ prior to each column name. So A ends up being "A$Dxa A$Dxb A$Dxc  A$Dxd  A$Dxe  A$Dxf"

This is to place in the expression below

```
paste(colnames(A), collapse=" + ")
```

So it ends up as

```
A$Dxa + A$Dxb  + A$Dxc + A$Dxd + A$Dxe + A$Dxf
```

Thank you

Comment: You have asked quite a few questions over the past few days. This question is pretty basic, are you sure you have done your best to find the answer yourself? Have you looked in `?paste`?

Comment: I am fairly new to R. I have tried with paste but I can not find a way to paste both colnames and the dataframe name as one single expression.

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? Why do you need these pasted together like this?

Comment: @AnandaMahto's question is important.  I (And assume others as well) have the feeling you're getting the right answer to the wrong question.

Comment: I was missing placing A initially in the expression as I tried with paste(colnames(A),sep="$", collapse=" + ") but I was getting no change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
A<-data.frame(Dxa=numeric(), Dxb=numeric(),  Dxc=numeric(),  
              Dxd=numeric(),  Dxe=numeric(),  Dxf=numeric() )
paste("A",colnames(A),sep="$", collapse=" + ")
```

result:

```
[1] "A$Dxa + A$Dxb + A$Dxc + A$Dxd + A$Dxe + A$Dxf"
```

**EDIT:**
Alternatively you can use (as Tyler Rinker suggested)

```
paste0("A$",colnames(A), collapse=" + ")
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to add all the columns of a data frame. You can do this with the `Reduce` function or the `rowSums` function:

```
# Sample Data
A = data.frame(Dxa=1:3, Dxb=1:3, Dxc=2:4, Dxd=7:5, Dxe=c(0, 0, 100))
A
#   Dxa Dxb Dxc Dxd Dxe
# 1   1   1   2   7   0
# 2   2   2   3   6   0
# 3   3   3   4   5 100

# Add Columns
Reduce("+", A)
# [1]  11  13 115
rowSums(A)
# [1]  11  13 115
apply(A, 1, sum)
# [1]  11  13 115
```

Creating an expression with `paste` and then evaluating that expression is not a good way to sum the columns of a data frame.